# How to validate part of response against custom XSD in soupUI?

Tags: soapui

In soapUI Pro I want to create an assertion to validate specified XML node of response against custom XSD. I know there is schema compliance assertion but I want to validate only part of response and against custom XSD (not from WSDL).

Comment: I don't get your question 100%. What exactly do you with "custom XSD"? Do you mean an XSD which is not used/referenced by the WSDL? If so what is the sense in this? Maybe you could edit your question to be more specific. That would help.

Comment: custom means not from WSDL but XSD from file

Comment: It makes perfect sense to as I am in a similar situation: I need to test an already released version of a WSDL that may or may not contain errors in the responses. One of the defects in the released WSDL is that it references bad/unexisting XSDs. Until we get a change to fix that, we need to validate the actual responses against local XSDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script assertion is needed to load part of response and validate it against schema loaded from file:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import javax.xml.XMLConstants
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory

def holder = new XmlHolder( messageExchange.responseContentAsXml )
holder.namespaces["sam"] = "http://www.example.org/sample/"
def node = holder["XPath"]

def factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI)
def schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(new FileReader("path_to_XSD_file")))
def validator = schema.newValidator()
validator.validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(node)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing you have received a response message do the following to validate only parts of the response:

- Switch to the form view of the response.
- Select the element or node you want to check.
- Right-click and select the assertion you need.

You can select a complete node or specific elements and values. Follow this link for more information:
[soapUI: Validating XML Messages](http://soapui.org/Functional-Testing/xpath-and-xquery-assertions.html)